# HighCharts for Arduino platform

Tags: highcharts, arduino

Arduino programmer; I have a NANO33 programmed to read National Weather Service and Air Now AQI data and show it on a 16X2 LCD screen. I’m using HTTP and JSON to read and parse the received responses using C++. Now I want to display all the data using HighCharts. I see that HighCharts supports the Python platform; does it also support the Arduino?

Comment: Why do you need an arduino, to read/display weather data from the internet?

Comment: I'm not sure what would you like to achieve. Do you want to plot the chart on the 16X2 LCD screen?

Comment: Can't use the LCD screen; it displays only characters. I will use a web browser to show any data I upload. See LCD screen picture of it here:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1LyJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can find all information about available official and community wrappers at the following website: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/wrappers/ .

Take note that Highcharts is a JavaScript library based on SVG rendering, dedicated to displaying graphs in a browser. You can also generate raster and vector images using an export module (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview).

Perhaps the solution would be converting chart images to Arduino array using some LCD Image Converter.

Comment: Looks like an export and upload so the data can be rendered in a browser is worth investigating.

Comment: To answer your question:
The purpose of this Arduino NANO33 project was to learn how to read the OpenWeather and AirNow APIs using HTTP commands and JSON parsing to extract the data. The Arduino scans a list of ZipCodes and displays the AQI (AirQualityIndex) results on the LCD screen as it’s primary purpose, and also the weather for that ZipCode as a secondary function. The Arduino displays the 6 color AQI scores on an LED strip that is easily visible from 20 feet away.  I want to see if it anyone has an Arduino C++ API.

Comment: As far as I know, Highcharts don't provide C++ API, but the main question what do you need Highcharts for in your project? What are your expectations from this library?

Comment: You are correct, there is no C++ API. All I want to do is to learn how to interface to HighCharts by taking the instantaneous weather and AQI (Air Quality Index) data I get from my Arduino from specific US ZipCodes and plot it over time. Maybe I can use the JavaScript libraries; I'll look.

Comment: I've noticed your comment on my previous question, so it seems I misunderstood you previously. I believe you don't need to use any special wrapper if you want to use a web browser to show charts. To use Highcharts you need only provide the data (sometimes it needs to be parsed to the relevant format). I recommend you to study "Working with data" docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro ; https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-data-api/ ; example demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/live-data